# How can i convert python nested dictionary to json file?

Tags: python, json

I have a python nested dictionary in the following format

```
data = {
        'item1': {
            'name': "A",
            'price': 10
        },
        'item2': {
            'name': "B",
            'price': 20
        }
    }
```

My expected output JSON file will be the following format

```
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "price": 20
  }
]
```

My code is

```
data = {
    'item1': {
        'name': "A",
        'price': 10
    },
    'item2': {
        'name': "B",
        'price': 20
    }
}
with open("my.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

But this code can't generate my expected JSON output format, how can i do it?

Comment: `list(data.values())`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
data = {
'item1': {
    'name': "A",
    'price': 10
    },
'item2': {
    'name': "B",
    'price': 20
    }
}

print(list(data.values()))
json.dump(list(data.values()), f)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not about JSON but about having a dictionary and expecting a list.
You can convert your dictionary entries to a list with `list(data.values())` and then export it to JSON.